# Cannot run VSTS LoadTest at a time

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have a VSTS project with a list of 30 LoadTest tests that I want to run sequentially. All tests are independent from each other.
When I try to run all the tests, it starts with the first test and it executes it perfectly, but once the first test is finished, it automatically starts to mark the rest of the tests as completed, but without executing them.

Do I have to configure any option to run all of them together? Am I missing something?
Note: when the first test is finished it also asks me if I want to view the "detailed results from the load test".

Any advice/comment is welcomed...

Thanks,
albert

**UPDATE (16/07/2010)**

More info... I'm trying to run the load tests as in the image that you can see at freeimagehosting.net/image.php?69cc93fa7b.gif. After the first loadtest is finished the rest of them are just marked as completed.

Answer (score 1):

The load tests are individual tests, and have never seen a way to execute them simultaneously. You create individual web tests that you then put into a load test to run.

Comment: Hi durilai,
Agree with you, but what I want to do is to run them sequentially, not at a same time. I mean, I want to collect some data and I don't want to be in front of my computer, waiting for each test to finish and then click on the next test.
Is it possible to run them sequentally, i.e. when the first finishes, the 2nd starts, etc.?

Cheers,
albert

Comment: Which version of VSTS are you running?

Comment: Here's what I have:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Version 3.5 SP1

Comment: Ok, are you just adding a single webtest to each loadtest? It looks like that is the case. You can add all webstests to the one loadtest by editing the test mix. Then you can specify the frequency and other properties.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My thought was that if I have the tests separate, they wouldn't "affect" the rest of the tests. How should I do it then? Create an scenario with all the tests I want to run and have the same distribution for all tests? How do I "say" that tests should be run sequentally? It would be perfect if you could give me some advice on this...
Many thanks